# VBScript SendKeys - Loop from Inputbox

Tags: vbscript

I basically have a software on a workplace computer (i'll call it Software X) where I want to tick boxes on thousands of rows. The fastest manual way to do it is, Press (SPACE) and then the (DOWN) key. So I'm trying to automate it with VBS sendkeys.

So... I want a script to prompt me for the number of times I want to loop my (SPACE) then (DOWN) and then do it that number of times.

I.e. if I input "100" into the box, it will then press (SPACE), then (DOWN) and do this 100 times.

```
WshShell.AppActivate "Software X"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
```

Comment: Search Google for *"How to loop in VBScript"*.....

Answer (score 0):

`For...Next` Loop will be your friend here. You also need to use `Sleep` method to give some time for the keystroke to send correctly.

```
Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim Value: Value = ""

Value = InputBox("Enter the number of times you want to SendKeys", "SendKeys - Software X", "1")

For iNum = 1 To CInt(Value)

  WshShell.AppActivate "Software X"
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys " "
  WScript.Sleep 500

  WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
  WScript.Sleep 500

Next
```

See more about [loops](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-loops.html) in VBScript.